# How to use null safety operator within a when branch in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

I have written a logic as shown below

```
fun snippet(value: String?): String {
    when (value?.toUpperCase()) {
        "A" -> "A"
        "B" -> "B"
        else -> ""
    }
}
```

Will it return `""` when the value of the variable `value` is `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will.

Or at least, it will once you've fixed a syntax error…  (The function is defined to return a String, but doesn't return anything.  To fix that, either add `return` before the `when` — or make it an expression body, replacing the first `{` with `=` and removing the last `}`.  The latter case is simpler for short functions, especially as you can then remove the return type too; but it's less suitable for longer ones.)

The easiest way to check is of course to run it yourself!  But yes, after fixing the syntax, it will indeed return an empty string if called with `null`.

What's going on is that the `?.` (safe call) operator will bypass the call to `toUpperCase()` if the LHS is `null`, and pass the `null` directly to the `when`.  And since `null` doesn't equal `"A"` or `"B"`, it falls through to the `else` branch, which gives the empty string.

As the other answer points out, you can of course check for `null` explicitly.  But Kotlin gives you several tools for handling nulls more concisely (such as the safe-call operator here), so you often don't need to.

Answer (score 3):

That `else` would catch it, you can also check for `null` directly in your `when` block:

```
when (value?.toUpperCase()) {
  ..
  null -> ""
}
```

Comment: Yes I could do this as well. Thanks for the suggestion.